# bash script does not show properly the new line and carriage return

Tags: bash, newline

I have a bash script that reads files, and replace chars. I have that to work but for some reason, the \n or \r are not showing ...

so for example I have a file: /tmp/a

```
abc
123
xyz
987
```

When I do:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  a=$(cat a)
  // replace stuff here (this works)
  echo -e $a
```

it shows:

```
abc xyz 987
```

BUT I want to show:

```
abc
xyz
987
```

how can I show the NL or CR therE?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting issue:

```
echo -e "$a"
```

keeps the newlines.

Comment: omg thanks, i feel dump now

Comment: @PatREllery Happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: awesome @Jens . wonderful